# Issue when playing video in local and url path

Tags: android

I play the video in VideoView

When I play from SD Card, it shows correct width and height in full screen. When I try to play from server, video Width is smaller and the video is re-sized.

How can I play the video in original size and full screen?

Comment: What is the server that you are using? Are you sure your server is not doing any kind of encoding or re sizing of the video file. Check the dimensions of files by comparing the original file and the downloaded file from server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) and implement the onPrepared method like the following code:

```
//prepare the video
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {        
    progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //First get the size of the video
    int videoWidth = player.getVideoWidth();
    int videoHeight = player.getVideoHeight();
    float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;  

    //get the size of the screen
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;

    //Adjust
    LayoutParams lp = surfaceViewFrame.getLayoutParams();
    if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
    } else {
        lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
        lp.height = screenHeight;
    }
    surfaceViewFrame.setLayoutParams(lp);

    if (!player.isPlaying()) {
        player.start();         
    }
    surfaceViewFrame.setClickable(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. please tell which reference we need to pass for "player" and "surfaceViewFrame".

Comment: The player is your MediaPlayer object, and the surfaceViewFrame is a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html).

Comment: Please send me any coding to play video in Surfaceview.now i played in videoview